# converting a nested list of userAccts and tweets to a dataframe [r]

Tags: r, list, dataframe, nested

I have a nested list of userAccts and tweets, the structure (in R) is below.

```
> str(botdetails[[1]][[100]])
Reference class 'status' [package "twitteR"] with 17 fields
 $ text         : chr "RT @jeremyslevin: 30% of the Bush tax cuts-which wrote the book on giveaways to the rich-went to the 1%. Trump "| __truncated__
 $ favorited    : logi FALSE
 $ favoriteCount: num 0
 $ replyToSN    : chr(0) 
 $ created      : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2017-09-02 07:59:32"
 $ truncated    : logi FALSE
 $ replyToSID   : chr(0) 
 $ id           : chr "903890119945359360"
 $ replyToUID   : chr(0) 
 $ statusSource : chr "<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/android\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for Android</a>"
 $ screenName   : chr "Monalisazelf"
 $ retweetCount : num 252
 $ isRetweet    : logi TRUE
 $ retweeted    : logi FALSE
 $ longitude    : chr(0) 
 $ latitude     : chr(0) 
 $ urls         :'data.frame':  0 obs. of  4 variables:
  ..$ url         : chr(0) 
  ..$ expanded_url: chr(0) 
  ..$ dispaly_url : chr(0) 
  ..$ indices     : num(0) 
 and 53 methods, of which 39 are  possibly relevant:
   getCreated, getFavoriteCount, getFavorited, getId, getIsRetweet, getLatitude,
   getLongitude, getReplyToSID, getReplyToSN, getReplyToUID, getRetweetCount,
   getRetweeted, getRetweeters, getRetweets, getScreenName, getStatusSource, getText,
   getTruncated, getUrls, initialize, setCreated, setFavoriteCount, setFavorited, setId,
   setIsRetweet, setLatitude, setLongitude, setReplyToSID, setReplyToSN, setReplyToUID,
   setRetweetCount, setRetweeted, setScreenName, setStatusSource, setText, setTruncated,
   setUrls, toDataFrame, toDataFrame#twitterObj
>
```

My issue is trying to convert the nested lists into a data frame, *twListtoDF* gives me this error:

```
> twListToDF(botdetails)
Error in twListToDF(botdetails) : 
  Elements of twList are not of an appropriate class
>
```

The help page for *twListtoDF* lists *status* as an appropriate class for the function:

```
Details

The classes supported by this function are status, user, and directMessage.
```

Can anyone suggest an effective method of creating an R dataframe from this nested list?

Comment: If the list has elements of unequal length, it cannot be flattened into a dataframe, because dataframes are defined as having equal length columns. This is a great resource I used to learn about purrr when starting out with lists: https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/index.html

Comment: I'd suggest using the rtweet package instead of twitteR. It has several benefits, notably easier authentication and returning data in well-formatted, easy to use data frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `purrr` and `jsonlite` packages have a `flatten()` function. The `jsonlite` version would probably work best for your purposes, as I'm assuming the Twitter API returns a JSON object (and the `purrr:flatten` only removes one layer of recursion at a time).

Info here: https://rdrr.io/cran/jsonlite/man/flatten.html

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are trying to extract user information of certain Twitter bot accounts. If you are looking at extracting all this information as a dataframe, try the following:

```
botdetails <- map(Botlist[1:100], ~twListToDF(lookupUsers(.x)))
botdf <- rbind.fill(botdetails)
```

Here, `Botlist` is a character vector containing the names of the Twitter accounts. `botdetails` will return you a list of dataframes which you can combine by using the `rbind.fill()` function from the `plyr` package.